# Linux - Is it possible to get mouse-input in C# from the bare Linux terminal (no DE)?

Tags: c#, linux, console

I want to make a simple "Desktop Environment" with keyboard and mouse functionality.
Now I can accept keypresses, but no mouse input (X Position, Y Position, Left Click, Right Click and Scroll wheel).
I'm asking my self how to do that in C#.

If anyone can help me, please do that.

I tried to call `Console.GetCursorPosition()` but that only returns the Console-Cursor.
My current solution is controlling the "Mouse Cursor" using the arrow keys.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/245948/how-can-i-use-the-mouse-in-a-virtual-terminal

Comment: Is your application simply a console application or does it draw graphics in its own window?

Comment: @gunr2171 It is a simple console application.

Answer (score 0):

Doing that on Linux would require ncurses support, which is non-trivial so your best bet is to use library like this one: https://github.com/gui-cs/Terminal.Gui